# Problem with datacube UI when I work with new dasaset added

Tags: raster-dataset, open-data-cube

I installed datacube from the official guide https://github.com/ceos-seo/data_cube_ui/tree/master/docs including the example. Everything works. I tried for simplicity to add a new app that calculates the NDVI even though I already knew it was present. The newly added app works on the example provided by the official datacube guide but does not work on the new data set I entered. When I click on submit the following error appears

> There was an unhandled exception during the processing of your task".

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

The general meaning of the message

> There was an unhandled exception during the processing of your task.

is that one or more Celery workers that perform the task's processing have experienced an error. You can check the error logs at `/var/log/celery` for more information.

One common issue with new apps experiencing errors is that the `Area` `Id` field does not allow the UI to match to the Data Cube product it needs to query. In the Django admin panel (path `/admin` - like `localhost/admin`), the `Area` menu is at `Dc_Algorithm -> Areas` where `->` denotes menu navigation. The product name queried by the UI for a given `Area` and `Satellite` is the `Satellite` `Product prefix` (see entries in `Dc_Algorithm -> Satellites`) prepended to the `Area` `Id`. If you see an error message in `/var/log/celery` like

> No products match search terms {...}.

and the product name is not the name of a product that should be queried for this `Area`, then this is likely the cause.

So if your satellite is Landsat 7 and your `Area` `Id` is `general`, then the Data Cube product and platform that will be queried is `ls7_ledaps_general` and `LANDSAT_7`, respectively. In the case of Landsat 8, the product and platform that will be queried is `ls8_lasrc_general` and `LANDSAT_8`, respectively.

In summary, an `Area` `Id` in `data_cube_ui` must be set based on the Data Cube products that should be queried for that Area, and the products and their platforms must be named based on the `Satellite` entries. However, an `Area` `Name` may be set to whatever you like and will be the name that appears for the `Area` when in a region selection menu (e.g. `custom_mosaic_tool/region_selection`).